# Will apt installation of Python 3.10 break the 3.8 version?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, python, ppa

Can I install Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 20.04 using `apt` without worrying that it breaks the Python 3.8?

I use Python 3.8 in many projects.

I'd run this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install python3.10
```

EDIT:

Going to use Python 3.10 in `virtualenv` only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The virtualenv utility creates virtual Python instances, each invokable with its own Python executable. Using Python 3.10 in a virtualenv environment will not have any effect on the Python version  that is used by default outside the Python virtual environment (Python 3.8 in Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: Thanks, Karel, I was rather curious if the installation itself `sudo apt install python3.10` won't break the existing version but I guess you implicitly says that it's ok to install it alongside the 3.8 version using `apt`.

Comment: You can also create multiple virtual Python instances, each instance with its own unique Python executable.